# Do mutiny and mutation have a common root?

Tags: etymology

[image: Mutiny etymology]

[image: Mutation etymology]

These words sound similar and the meaning is close, too - in both cases something is changing.
Etymology I found implies they are not connected to each other, but I'm still curious.

Comment: Although both words indicate change, the *way* in which that change happens is opposite. One is adaptive, the other confrontational.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While they have separate roots, it's worth noting a couple of points.

First, among the obsolete senses of "mutation" noted by the OED is "revolution" or "civil insurrection".   According to the OED, this sense of "mutation" *may* be at least partly a borrowing from French "meutation", "meute", which comes from Latin "movere":

> In sense ‘revolution’ (see sense 1b) perhaps partly after Middle French *meutacion* riot, revolt (early 15th cent.) < *meute* uprising

The similarity of *movo, movere* and *muto, mutare* is noted by the *Dictionnaire Étymologique de la Langue Latine* (A. Ernout & A. Meillet, 1932), but they ultimately dismiss any etymological link:

> L'idée de changement est inséparable de celle de mouvement et les sujets parlants ont souvent associé *muto* à *moveo*; de là des emplois comme ceux qu'on rencontre dans Plaute, Am. 274 ... et dans les langues romanes; cf v. ital. *mutare* "voyager", fr. *remuer*, etc. à côté de *muer* "changer [de peau]" etc.); ... Ces emplois et ce sens ont donné lieu à l'étymologie *mouitare*  > mutare "mouvoir fréquemment, déplacer", puis "changer".  Mais, d'une part, le fréquentatif de *mouere* est *motare* et, d'autre part, le sens premier de *mutare* est bien "changer", comme le prouvent le dérivé *mutuus* et les composés *commutare*, *permutare*; et la forme *commoetacula* enseigne que l'*u* de *mutare* est issu d'un ancien *oi*.

In other words:

> The idea of change is inseparable from that of movement, and speakers have often associated *muto* with *moveo*; whence such uses as we meet in Plautus, Am. 274 ... and in Romance languages; cf. Old Italian *mutare* "travel", French *remuer* "move", etc. alongside *muer* "change [one's skin]" etc. ... These uses and this meaning have given rise to the etymology *mouitare* > *mutare* "move frequently, move" then "change".  But first of all, the frequentative of *mouere* is *motare*, and secondly, the original sense of *mutare* is indeed "change", as proved by the derivative *mutuus* and the compounds *commutare*, *permutare*; and we learn from the form *commoetacula* that the *u* of *mutare* derives from an archaic *oi*.

Comment: "The idea of change is inseparable from that of movement." While I don't doubt the historicity of this notion, it sounds archaic to my modern ears. But perhaps I'm alone in that.

Comment: @jpmc26 for there to be a change, there must be a movement from a previous state to another. It makes sense to me..

Comment: @Shautieh Not saying you *can't* make sense of it. I'm just saying that I don't think that, as a society, we strongly associate the notion of change with movement anymore.

Comment: “You’ve come a long way,” is how I would describe someone who has changed a lot. Movement is probably the most common metaphor for change.

Answer (score 9):

The Online Etymology Dictionary traces both words back to different Proto-Indo-European roots. The word "mutiny" goes back to a root "meue" meaning "to push away." The word "mutate" goes back to a root "mei" meaning "to change, move, or go." The two meanings are related in that both involve motion or change, and there is similarity in pronunciation. It is plausible, therefore, to speculate that ultimately the two words are both derived from a common root. But that speculation has no historical evidence. A common root, if there is one, precedes the development of Proto-Indo-European. For at least the last 4000 years, the words have had different histories.